# Serialisable stable representation of a type

Tags: haskell, serialization, types

I'm working on a data structure that I would like to serialize, with an API like:

```
serialize :: Foo a -> ByteString
deserialize :: ByteString -> Maybe (Foo a)
```

In my case `a` is a phantom parameter; there are no values in `Foo` to witness that type, but preserving the type is important.

GHC provides `Typeable` which can give me a `TypeRep` form which I can extract a [`Fingerprint`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-Fingerprint-Type.html#v:Fingerprint) , but I don't believe that representation is necessarily stable across different architectures and versions of GHC.

Is there some way I can reliably serialize a type representation, perhaps with the new static pointers thing, or something else in `base`?

**EDIT**: I've implemented this type versioning functionality (sort of "hashing of types") in [hashabler](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashabler-1.2.1); see `TypeHash`.

Comment: I’m curious about the answer for its own sake, but I’d be worried that any method like this is going to make it hard to, say, refactor by moving a type into a different module, or renaming it.

Comment: It would help if you gave more information about the type. There are serialization libraries for a lot of different types of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to play games with `Typeable`, as the [binary-typed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/binary-typed) package does. It allows you to remove and reconstruct fingerprints as needed. I'm not sure if that will work for types manufactured on the fly. Another option is to manufacture some tags yourself, as long as you know or can figure out which values have the same phantoms. An extreme approach might be to build a `Map` of the `TypeRep`s you see along the way, mapping them to unique `Int` values. On the other end, you can make an `IntMap` from the tags to functions that wrap up the values properly.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! It occurs to me that if I want to answer "is this the correct/same/requested type?", I need to decide "correct type" with respect to what aspect of the data (as both the internal representations and exposed bits of a type change over versions, and even across architectures). In my case I'm dealing with hashes. I'm thinking of adding a method something like `typeIdentity :: UUID` to the [`Hashable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashabler-1.0/docs/Data-Hashabler.html#t:Hashable) class. Might take some further explanation why I think that's justified.

Comment: @jberryman, it kind of sounds like your use case was pretty different from what I imagined. Now I'm curious what those phantoms are about.

Comment: It's a bloom filter. We constrain it to a single type `BloomFilter Things` because our hashing library cannot ensure the well-behavedness of hashes of two different types with respect to each other (i.e. "similar" objects of different types might hash to the same value, which you might consider a collision). Of course no values of type `Things` appear in `BloomFilter` since it's just a byte array. Incidentally I'm also considering type-level nat parameters for length etc. so that it can be a Monoid, but I'm not sure that's going to be feasible

Comment: @jberryman, this is strongly reminiscent of what Ed Kmett's hyperloglog does. Read the GitHub source-it's been cleaned up quite a lot since the last release.